# Saving textBox input to .txt file without use of SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I want to eliminate the need for SaveFileDialog and just add the ability for a user to save the input `onClick` without having to go through the `SaveFileDialog`. The filename will be set by `txtModuleName.Text`and the location/directory and file type will always remain the same.

```
 string Saved_Module = "";

        SaveFileDialog saveFD = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFD.InitialDirectory = "C:/Modules/";
        saveFD.Title = "Save your file as...";
        saveFD.FileName = txtModuleName.Text;
        saveFD.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Saved_Module = saveFD.FileName;
            RichTextBox allrtb = new RichTextBox();
            // This one add new lines using the "\n" every time you add a rich text box
            allrtb.AppendText(txtModuleName.Text + "\n" + ModuleDueDate.Text + "\n" + txtModuleInfo.Text + "\n" + txtModuleLO.Text);
            allrtb.SaveFile(Saved_Module, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

RE-ATTACK - How do I replace the use of the Dialog box when saving with a simple button that says 'Save' which OnClick uses the txtModuleName.Text as its name and saves it to a set directory C:/Modules/ in the form of a .txt file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the user supposed to provide the filename and location without the use of the `SaveFileDialog`? The purpose of the dialog is to ask the user where the file should be saved and what it should be called. What do you propose to use as the alternative that would be better than the dialog every single Windows application on the planet uses for that purpose?

Comment: What the user inputs into each text box determines the filename, the directory will remain the same as will the extension.

Comment: So what is your question? Remove the code related to the SaveFileDialog and provide the path and filename to the `allrtb.SaveFile` method instead of what you're passing as `Saved_Module`.

Comment: When I attempt this eg. 

`RichTextBox allrtb = new RichTextBox();
                // This one add new lines using the "\n" every time you add a rich text box
                allrtb.AppendText(txtModuleName.Text + "\n" + ModuleDueDate.Text + "\n" + txtModuleInfo.Text + "\n" + txtModuleLO.Text);
                allrtb.SaveFile("C:/Modules/", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`

all I get is an error when trying to save OnClick.

Comment: The question I have asked is clear. 

How do I replace the use of the Dialog box when saving with a simple button that says 'Save' which `OnClick` uses the `txtModuleName.Text` as its name and saves it to a set directory `C:/Modules/` in the form of a `.txt` file. That is all I would like to know.

Comment: Whether the question you've asked is clear or not is not up to you. It's up to readers of the question. And I've told you - you need to provide a path and filename to `allrtb.SaveFile`, and you're providing only the path.

Comment: Please could you possibly elaborate more on this method and also possibly provide an example as to how to solve my problem/question in greater detail in the Answer Question section. This would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Done, although it would have been much better for you to attempt to do this yourself based on what I explained. *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.* Try to learn to fish instead of asking for meals. When people point you to a solution, try to learn to explore on your own rather than asking to be handed a coded solution. You'll do much better in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full path and filename to `RichTextBox.SaveFile` instead of using `SaveFileDialog.FileName`. Add `using System.IO;`, and then use something similar to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Saved_Module = Path.Combine("C:\\Module", txtModuleName.Text);
            allrtb.SaveFile(Saved_Module, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        }
```